# What should I do about my simple question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568194/my-stylesheet-do-not-work?noredirect=1#comment74186624_43568194

But at first I didn't know what the issue was caused by. Now I know it was a typo by me.

On Stack Overflow, typo questions should not posted on the site. So what to do with that? Should I delete the post? But somewhere on Stack Overflow I found a post says you should not delete your post, otherwise the answerers cannot find the question they answered.

So should I do not delete that, and accept the downvotes?

Comment: In the future, you should also try to find a more explicit title. *"XX does not work"* does not describe the problem.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, you should delete the post. You can delete your own post unless: it has multiple answers; you've accepted an answer; or the answers have upvotes (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/248731)).

When the answer turns out to just be a typo, it makes it unlikely that the question and its answer will be useful to other readers, so there isn't much point keeping it around.

Comment: and when it actually is useful, there is almost always a question about it already (and a dozen duplicates)