# What should I do with a question that is too simple?

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840745/modules-in-python-tkinter-as-in-vba), which I answered with a comment directing the user to an online tutorial. It is a perfectly reasonable question for a brand new Python programmer to have, but it doesn't really seem to me to have much value on Stack Overflow. What should I do with it? Should I answer it, downvote it, flag it, or leave it alone?

It currently has one downvote, and it has been active for around seven hours.

My question is similar to the following, but it differs in that the asker did not make an obvious error and was not asking for us to do any work for him:

- *[What to do with question about nonexistent problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280632/what-to-do-with-question-about-nonexistent-problem)*
- *[Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions)*
- *[What should I do about my simple question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348313/what-should-i-do-about-my-simple-question)*

Comment: It is after a long time since you asked this question but I would like to add that many of these "simple" questions are being closed for debugging details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the only problem is that it's too simple, then a simple downvote would be fine.  The downvote indicates that it's not useful for others.

It's not *otherwise* off-topic or *otherwise* eligible to be closed, so trying to close it would not be <s>constructive</s> appropriate.

Comment: "If the only problem is that it's too simple, then a simple downvote would be fine." Why downvote a question that we don't have any similar answer in the community for it? || "The downvote indicates that it's not useful for others." if the question is too simple, then so be it, it's useful, but only to a smaller group, as much as a sophisticated question is useful to a senior group. My point is as long as the person has done research, can't find related questions and has shown his attempt to find an answer elsewhere then the question is a good candidate. It being simple is irrelevant.

Answer (score 14):

**A simple question doesn't necessarily mean a bad question.**

What you need to ask is, does this question serve a purpose? Will other users find this question useful in the future or is this a one time question that is usually known? When you do a quick search, does a solution pop right up, indicating a lack of research?

Users on all levels come to Stack Overflow to find answers. If a question is asked properly, formatted well, and shows proper research, even if it is a beginner question, if it is not a duplicate and you feel others would benefit from it in the future, go ahead and answer it.

The question you linked can use some formatting help and doesn't show proper research. That is why it is not a good question, and not because it is a simple question.

---

If you want an example question backing my point, two years ago I asked the following question:
[Difference between ./ and ~/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and)

Before asking the question, I searched for quite some time, and couldn't find an answer. Even today, two years later, if you search for "Difference between ./ and ~/", the correct answer does not show up.

As soon as I asked the question, however, it received a downvote, the reason I'm assuming being that it looks very simple.

I won't argue, the question is quite simple, and so is the solution. This, however, was an honest question that I couldn't figure out. It's on topic and can be helpful to others in the future. Just because it is simple, doesn't mean it shouldn't have been answered. I am quite thankful to the users who answered and helped me understand the concept.